# covariance matrix from a community list with grouping factors

Tags: r, data.table

I am still learning to use data.table (from the [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package) and even after looking for help on the web and the help files, I am still struggling to do what I want.
I have a large data table with over 60 columns (the first three corresponding to factors and the remaining to response variables, in this case different species) and several rows corresponding to the different levels of the treatments and the species abundances. A very small version looks like this:

```
> TEST<-data.table(Time=c("0","0","0","7","7","7","12"),
             Zone=c("1","1","0","1","0","0","1"),
             quadrat=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1),
             Sp1=c(0,4,29,9,1,2,10),
             Sp2=c(20,17,11,15,32,15,10),
             Sp3=c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0)) 
>setkey(TEST,Time)

> TEST
    Time Zone quadrat Sp1 Sp2 Sp3
1:    0    1       1   0  20   1
2:    0    1       2   4  17   0
3:    0    0       3  29  11   1
4:   12    1       1  10  10   0
5:    7    1       1   9  15   1
6:    7    0       2   1  32   1
7:    7    0       3   2  15   1
```

I need to calculate the sum of the covariances for each Zone x quadrat group. If I only had the species list for a given Zone x quadrat combination, then I could use the cov() function but using cov() in the same way that I would use mean() or sum() in

```
 Abundance = TEST[,lapply(.SD,mean),by="Zone,quadrat"]
```

does not work  as I get the following error message:

```
Error in cov(value) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

I understand why but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

What I exactly want is to be able to get, for each Zone x quadrat combination, the covariance matrix of all the species across all the sampling Time points. From each matrix, I then need to calculate the sum of the covariances of all pairs of species, so that then I can have a sum of covariance for each Zone x quadrat combination.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your `test` does not work, since the columns are not the same length. It also doesn't look like the `TEST` you show here. Also, do you need the `Time` variable for your example? Finally, what would your desired output look like? A list of matrices?

Comment: My apologies, wrong version copied in: I've edited the question to correct it. Yes I need the Time variable because this is the variable across which the covariances should be calculated. I've also edited the question to be more specific about what I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, something like `TEST[,sum(upper.tri(cov(.SD))),by='Zone,quadrat',.SDcols=paste('Sp',1:3,sep='')]`?

Comment: THis does not work although I think it's going in the right direction: the sum function seems to calculate the number of TRUE values from the upper.tri function, not the actual values.

Comment: @Frank, By looking the upper.tri functions and other questions from people, I've tweeked the above code to :  `Cov= TEST[,sum(cov(.SD)[upper.tri(cov(.SD), diag = TRUE)]), by='Zone,quadrat', .SDcols=paste('Sp',1:3,sep='')]` but it's still not enough, as it's including hte values of the diagonal in the sum, which I do not want.

Comment: OK, So after changing the above code to `diag = FALSE`, I think it works

Comment: Ok, glad you've figured it out! You can post what you've found as an answer (below) for people who come across your question in the future, and maybe explain it by repeating what you found useful in those other questions, or linking to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help provided above by @Frank and some additional searching that I did around the use of the `upper.tri` function, the following code works:

`Cov= TEST[,sum(cov(.SD)[upper.tri(cov(.SD), diag = FALSE)]), by='Zone,quadrat', .SDcols=paste('Sp',1:3,sep='')]`

The initial version proposed, where `upper.tri()` did not appear in [ ] only extracted logical values from the covariance matrix and having `diag = FALSE` allowed to exclude the diagonal values before summing the upper triangle of the matrix. In my case, I didn't care whether it was the upper or lower triangle but I'm sure that using `lower.tri()` would work equally well.

I hope this helps other users who might encounter a similar issue.